# How can I break the sequence of wrongly typed commands in emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

How can I break the sequence of wrongly typed commands in emacs? For example I type `M-x`, then I change my mind and decide to Copy a text. So I have to type `M-w`, but the problem is previously typed `M-x` . How can I effectively do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>C-g</kbd> which calls `keyboard-quit`.

Comment: Isn't there any simpler solution? like VIM which we can use ESC

Comment: @Lion: You can bind it to any key you like. `Esc` has a special meaining in Emacs, but you can press it 3 times to call `keyboard-escape-quit` :-)

Comment: <kbd>C-g</kbd> is as simple as it gets in Emacs, because that's the standard "quit" binding that works in all such situations. (It also interrupts running Lisp code.)